# Solving a recursion efficiently

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, numerical-methods, recursion

I have a recursive formula $$v(n+1) = v(n)\dfrac{1+v(n-1)-n}{1+v(n-1)-v(n)}$$
and I also know $$v(1)=2v(0)$$ $$n+1 \le v(n+1) \le v(n)+1.$$

I wish to find, for example, $v(10)$ more efficiently than my current method does. That involves using the numerical instability of the recursion, by trying different values of $v(0)$, taking them forward until one of the inequalities is not met, then adjusting my estimate for $v(0)$ using a bisection method, and trying again.

If I use sufficient decimal precision (about $45$ decimal places in this example) for my calculations and search then I can get a value for $v(0)$ of about $0.6245357205\ldots$ which then gives a value for $v(10)$ of about $10.0000000114\ldots$.

But this seems excessive, especially if I want $v(n)$ for larger $n$; I ended up finding $v(0)$ to $2000$ decimal places in http://www.se16.info/hgb/lockedbox.pdf

I was wondering whether there might be an alternative approach.

Comment: It seems natural to consider $u(n) = v(n) - n$ instead.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, this quantity would need to stay between $0$ and $v_0$. I wonder is it monotonically increasing, decreasing, or neither.

Comment: $u(n) = v(n) - n$ is monotonically decreasing since $v(n+1) \le v(n)+1$.  In fact for large $n$ and knowing empirically $u(0)=v(0)$, it seems clear that $u(n)\,(n+1)! \to 0.4566281571\ldots$ from above, so you could even consider $w(n)= u(n)\,(n+1)! = (v(n)-n)\,(n+1)!$ but it does not make the recursive formula easier.

Comment: It might be possible to express each number or perhaps the ratios, as continued fractions; the first relation smacks of this, and it would guarantee a unique solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Suggested Improvement for Algorithm

I hope I understand the question correctly. My interpretation is as follows:

**Question:** Given some $n$, we want to find a good* approximate value for $v_n$, where $v_n$ is defined as above.

#### Algorithm

We start of with some "reasonable" approximation for $v_0$- just to a few decimal places is all we need. Now we initialise an interval to $[n, n+v_0]$. From below we know that $v_n$ must lie in this range. From here, iterate with the following.

1. Set $v_n$ to the midpoint of the interval.
2. Compute the recurrence forward until it fails, high or low, note the number of steps it took to fail as $k$.
3. If $k$ is sufficiently big, then stop.
4. Else note the direction of failure, chop the interval accordingly, and return to the first step.

#### Notes

This is essentially the same as the method given, with one major difference: we *start* with an approximation of $v_n$, not $v_0$. This way, we do not waste time on tiny perturbations in the value of $v_0$ that quickly lead to large disturbances. In fact we never fail the test for $v_n$, because we *start* with an approximation for $v_n$ in the known range. Arguably then this is a better approach than starting at $v_0$, though it really depends on what is meant by a "good" approximation- see below. It also depends on my interpretation of the question. Certainly it lacks an explicit error term.

For this method, we don't need a massively accurate approximation of $v_0$ to begin with. It would be overkill. This is because we're going to chop the interval $[n, n+v_0]$, so fine-tuning $v_0$ seems pointless. However, after glancing at the linked pdf, I do worry somewhat about the term $u_n = v_n - n$, which seems to tend towards zero by a factor of $\frac1{n!}$. In this case, starting at the midpoint of $[n, n+v_0]$ seems a bit foolish, and we'd really be better starting much closer to $n$. I did not think further about this though, as I do not know where the inverse factorial relationship originates, so I leave it up to the questioner to investigate this issue.

*The definition of "good" is a bit hazy here. The standard interpretation would be an error, absolute or percentage, from the "true" value (if it is unique). However, the approach I take here follows the style of the questioner. We say that an approximation is good to $k$ steps for $v_n$ if the following $k$ terms $v_{n+1}$ up to $v_{n+k}$, computed via the recurrence, respect the inequalities given. Another interpretation would be to also take some terms *before* $v_n$, computing the recurrence backwards, but I'll leave this for later work.

### Some old Observations

- $v_0 \geq 0$. Otherwise, $v(1)=2v(0)$ would be negative, contradicting the second condition, in particular $n + 1 \leq v_{n + 1}$, which for $n=0$ gives $1 \leq v_1$.
- For all natural numbers $n$, including $0$, we have that $n \leq v_n \leq n + v_0$. This follows from the second condition and a little bit of induction.
- $v_n$ is monotonically increasing, from the last condition and the experimental fact that $0 < v_0 < 1$

A question I would ask is: does a non-trivial, exact, solution exist? If so, is it unique?

Comment: Since any sequence, if it fails either inequality, must fail one before the other (lower starting values of $v(0)$ fail the first, while higher values fail the second), there is a non-empty subset of the real numbers of values of $v(0)$ whose sequences do not fail either. The numerical instability suggests this non-empty set contains a single value of $v(0). An exact solution exists as these are the values of a particular two-player zero-sum game.

Comment: On your first point, it is equally easy to show $v(0) \le 1$ as otherwise $v(1) =2v(0) \gt v(0)+1$, and that $v(0) \ge \frac 12$ as otherwise $v(1) \le 1$.  it is not much harder to show $v(0) \ge \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$   as otherwise $v(2) \lt 1$ and even  $v(0) \le \frac{\sqrt{17}+1}{8}$ as otherwise $v(2) \gt v(1)+1$.  It then starts to get harder.

Comment: Showing any numerical solution is unique may be harder, but for example they all fall between $0.624535720582943329384682938284321195879387410$ and $0.624535720582943329384682938284321195879387411$, and similarly with many more decimal places, which is suggestive that there is only one.

Comment: Hmmm yes, it certainly does "feel" like there is just one solution hiding in the unit interval somewhere. I deleted my third point about the trivial solution, based on your observations. I'm trying to think of a proof strategy for uniqueness...

Comment: As you say, not an answer

Comment: Indeed. Certainly not bounty worthy. I did try to come up with a strategy for showing uniqueness. I failed. I realise that it's not really uniqueness that you're after anyway. You want a faster way to generate approximations to arbitrary terms in a sequence than just iterative application of the recurrence. On this, I'm afraid I must bow out as I am no expert. It seems like something for generating functionologists or Z-transformers. I'm out of my depth here. Good luck with the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem iterating the recurrence ten times to find $v(10)$.  My problem is that my method requires doing up to ten steps  almost $150$ times using at least $45$ decimal places each time.  More times with more decimal places if I want $v(n)$ for $n \gt 10$

Comment: OK, let me see if I understand your algorithm correctly. You have a range $[l, u]$ estimating $v_0$. You take the midpoint of the range, and iterate the recurrence until it fails. Then, depending on the nature of the failure (higher/lower), you chop the interval accordingly, and repeat again. If this is more or less what you are doing, why do you say "up to ten steps". Surely the failure can happen anywhere, before *or* after ten steps? Also, surely the number of decimal places increases with each iteration, as the interval becomes finer? I suspect the solution is irrational. Thoughts?

Comment: My "up to ten steps" is really shorthand for saying that I want to get to at least to $v(10)$ without failing.  If I test with $v(0)=0.6245357205$ or $0.6245357206$ then I fail at $v(6)$, hence the "up to".  What I have done is to use a fixed number of decimal places: I could change this but given the arithmetic operations of the recurrence, I suspect it is safer to have more precision in the calculations than in the $v(0)$ being tested.  Otherwise, your description is broadly speaking what I did: for $45$ decimal places involving about $150$ test numbers.

Comment: I still don't see why you stop at $v_{10}$ for an approximation of $v_{10}$. Too long to answer in comment. I have updated my answer. Please have a look.